# string pattern matching using perl regex

Tags: regex, perl

i need to verify a string which contains year or not 
for example spiderman (2014)
how can i?

Comment: What have your tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

So many things look like a year, especially if unbounded. Since you appear to be looking for the production years of filmed media, we can at least restrict it to the 1900s and 2000s.

```
$str =~ /\b(?:19|20)[0-9]{2}\b/
```

If the year in which you are interested will always be in parens, the following will be better:

```
$str =~ /\((?:19|20)[0-9]{2}\)/
```

Comment: this regex is overkill... and you just copied my answer >.>
not to mention what if there was a year like 1856?

Comment: @Seekheart, LOL! Not only would take me longer to copy your regexp than to write it myself, yours it thinks that `(0001)` and `(૪૪૪૪)` are years. There's also the detail that my solution most similar to yours was posted 4 minutes before you posted yours.

Comment: @Seekheart, Films did not exist in 1856. While films predate 1900, I wager those aren't production dates he is going to encounter. On the off chance that he could encounter that, altering the pattern to support the 1800s would be trivial and obvious.

Comment: Even regardless of the nature of the number this solution incorporates the concept of qualifying the number somehow.  You can easily construct the pattern for the match such as `$pattern = encode_year()`, where the sub can come from a module, class ... and off you go to a good and flexible design.  Given the hint in the question it is in fact a fully reasonable solution just as it stands.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the movies all have 4 digit years with parenthesis then the following
will suit your fancy ;)

```
my $test = 'spiderman (2014)';

if ($test =~ m/[(]+\d{4}[)]+/){
     print "Year is present!\n";
}
```

Comment: @ikegami how? the regex provided requires there to be a parenthesis followed by 4 numbers and end with a parenthesis...

Comment: 1234 ... a good year?